# Compare a List<T> to a database table

Tags: c#, mysql, plsql

I am working with an object that contains the **SessionID** and the **EmployeeID**.
Based on that, I should compare whether the Database table contains that employee for that session.

If the table **contains** the record and my object **does**, nothing happens.

If the table **contains** the record and my object **doesn't**, it should be removed from the table.

If the table **does not contain** the record and my object **does**, it should be added to the table.

Seems like a quick job but I'm struggling a bit.

EDIT:

Obviously the table has the **SessionID** and the **EmployeeID** columns, as my object's properties.

Here is the actual code:

```
foreach (Employee _emp in MyObj.Employees)
{
    Command.Parameters.Add(":sessionid", MyObj.SessionID);
    Command.Parameters.Add(":employeeid", _emp.EmployeeID);

    Command.CommandText = getEmployeeID;

    int employeeID;

    Int32.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Command.ExecuteScalar()), out employeeID);

    // If the employee is not in the db, add it

    if (employeeID == 0)
    {
        Command.CommandText = insertEmployee;

        [[Various Parameters]]

        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Command.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    // if the employee is in the db but not in the current list, remove it from the db

    else if (employeeID != Convert.ToInt32(_emp.EmployeeID))
    {
        Command.CommandText = deleteEmployee;

        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so by now I can check if an Employee exists in the database, and according to that insert a record or not.

The thing is, the code will never go into the **else if** condition, because MyObj.Employees does not contain the records I want to delete from the database anymore, so

```
employeeID != Convert.ToInt32(_emp.EmployeeID)
```

will always result false, since the only objects in MyObj.Employees are the ones I am checking the existence in the db.

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: @Thomas Here is the updated code

Comment: one thing of hnote:   else if (employeeID != 0   the employeeID != 0 is not needed there as you are in the else part of employeeID == 0.

Comment: that side: what exactly does not work there?

Comment: What does "struggling a bit" mean - what is the problem?

Comment: The fact is that if now I clear my List<Employees> and fill it again with other objects, that code will just **add** the new Employees to the DB, without actually deleting the old ones, which are not in "MyObj.Employees" anymore.

Comment: I'd like to load the whole list of employees from the DB, like
`select employeeid from employees where sessionid = [any number]`
This shall give me all the employee ids listed for that particular session.
Now I'd like to **compare** that list with my object, and make changes to the db accorting to that.

Comment: @Thomas See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code:

```
Command.Parameters.Add(":sessionid", MyObj.SessionID);

// Delete all the employees for that session

Command.CommandText = DeleteEmployees;

Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Command.Parameters.Clear();

// Insert all the current employees in the list object in the db

Command.CommandText = InsertEmployees;

foreach (Company.Employee _emp in MyObj.Employees)
{
     [[ various parameters]]

    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Command.Parameters.Clear();
}
```